# Vue.js binding attribute with v-model

Tags: vuejs2

I am reading a book, the author says that is is possible to change the text of a parent component using the v-model directive. How would that be? Suppose I have a child with a text input and I want to use its data  to change the text inside a div on the parent, again, how would that be?

The author says:

"If it is a native event, such as input, it's even more simple. Just bind the needed attribute to the
child component as a v-model and then call the $emit method with the name of the event (for
example, input) from the child component"

I didn't understand her statements. I will provide some code, so that the answerer can point me to the right direction.

parent:

```
 <template>
   <div> {{ somevalue }} </div>

    <child-component v-model="somevalue"></child-component>

 </template>
```

What do I do in the child?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? You want to change `{{somevalue}}` from within the child component?

Comment: Yes, I want to change somevalue from within the child component. I am learning react and I am able to pass data from the child component to the parent through events using the v-on directive. With v-model I didn't understand. I already read the documentation but I really didn't find a way to implement the author's statements.

Comment: This is not recommended. Change the parent this is way it's against best practices and you get a warning on the console. It's just for didactic purposes.

Comment: The question marked as "duplicate" was very clarifying.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate though very similar .. glad you got it figured out